# How to create a new column in R based on a condition in another column?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a column with weather variables values in my data set against disease severity. I am struggling to create a new column when precipitation was greater than zero & mean wind speed equal to or greater than zero ( precipitation > 0 & wind_speed >=0). In simple words, I want to create a new column for wind speed when it was raining to determine splash dispersal effect on disease severity. The key is I don't want to introduce NA's because I'll end up with fewer rows if I remove NAs. How can I achieve this? Thanks very much for any assistance.[image]

df%>%
mutate(new_wspd=ifelse( precipitation>0 &wind_speed >=0, wind_speed,NA)) can do it, but it introduces NAs.  If I use na.rm = TRUE, I'll end up with fewer rows that will effect other weather variables influence. I can't afford that.

Comment: If you don't want NA, what do you want as replacement

Comment: Hello Ahsaan, ¿it helps for your needs to put a zero instead of NA? `df%>% mutate(new_wspd=ifelse( precipitation>0 &wind_speed >=0, wind_speed, 0))`

Comment: Perhaps you need a "factor" variable in your model? `df%>% mutate(precip_wind = factor(ifelse( precipitation>0 &wind_speed >=0, "yes" , "no")))`  then you can do `lm(disease_severity ~ (wind_speed + precipitation):precip_wind, df)` or similar?

Comment: Hi Ric, Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I can't have zeros either

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason you do not want NAs is to avoid loosing data when removing rows with NAs in some further steps, you can just do what you thought:

> mutate(new_wspd=ifelse( precipitation>0 &wind_speed >=0, wind_speed,NA))

And then use drop_na when you need to remove NAs:

> drop_na(!new_wspd)

But I am not sure to understand what it should be if not NAs.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. You have to do something with NA to avoid getting errors. Thanks

Comment: I still do not understand what you want to have on the lines where your criteria do not apply. Blank spaces? They are the same as NA... I think that is where your problem is, and this is not a coding issue.

Comment: I just don't to loose data - could be anything where criteria doesn't match. I can add zeros instead of NAs, but results would be misleading